Discord bot joins the previous voice channel I have been(discord.js)
My discord bot joins the voice channel currently I'm being on when i use /vc join then I disconnect the bot using /vc disconnect and switch to another channel in the same guild(server). After then I use the /vc join again but the bot joins the previous channel I've been.
So I basically wrote a code using JavaScript:
const connections = new Map(); //This line at the top of my code

if (interaction.commandName === "vc") {
        let member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.user.id);
        let channel = member.voice.channel;

        if (!channel) {
            interaction.reply({ content: "You must be in a voice channel to use this command", ephemeral: true }); 
            return;
        }

        if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'join') {
            member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.user.id); //I also tried adding let beginning of the line
            channel = member.voice.channel; //I also tried adding let beginning of the line
        
            let connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: channel.id,
                guildId: channel.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });
            connections.set(channel, connection);
            interaction.reply({ content: "Joined the voice channel!" });
        }
        
        else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'disconnect') {
            member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.user.id); //I also tried adding let beginning of the line
            channel = member.voice.channel; //I also tried adding let beginning of the line

            let connection = connections.get(channel);
            if (connection) {
                connection.destroy();
                connections.delete(channel);
                interaction.reply({content: "disconnected"});
            } 

            else {
                interaction.reply({content: "not in vc"});
            }
        }
    }

It should be working like this:
1- Gets the ID of the channel just joined and saves to connections Map
2- Disconnects from the channel and deletes the ID of the channel from the connections Map
3- Joins to another channel without any problem
I think the problem is about connections Map but I couldn't figure out how would I solve that problem.
